# AsEnumerable - Does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core 6 I have the following:

```
IEnumerable<Orders> orders = await _dbContext.Orders.Where(x => x.Closed == null).AsEnumerable();

foreach (Order order in orders) {
  // Do something
}
```

I get the error:

```
'IEnumerable<Order>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Order>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Should I use ToListAsync() in this situation? I understand the options:

```
IQueryable<Order> orders = _context.Orders.Where(x => x.Closed == null).AsQueryable();

IList<Order> orders = await _context.Orders.Where(x => x.Closed == null).ToListAsync();
```

But what `AsEnumerable` does exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsEnumerable()` returns `IEnumerable` which executes query synchronously at start of enumeration, so there is no `Task` to await. If you have to enumerate asynchronously, use `AsAsyncEnumerable()` and `await foreach`

```cs
var orders = await _dbContext.Orders.Where(x => x.Closed == null)
    .AsAsyncEnumerable();

await foreach (Order order in orders) 
{
   // Do something
}
```